# Installation tag Cleanup

Tags: discussion, retag-request

According to figures as of October 19, 2014, there are almost 9400 questions tagged as [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation).

I propose that we have a month-long cleanup event where all of these questions are sorted either into [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation), [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation), both, none, or other.

This will finally nuke this tag and clean up the site.

My proposal has four parts:

- GUI for review -- An announcement is put on the AU site talking about this, and how any user with 10+ rep can join in the fun. When a link is clicked, they are teleported to a special review board where they can review a question and choose which tag(s) to put said question into.
- Users under 500 rep will get their tag choices approved, or have them voted in by 3 500- rep users.
- Users at 500+ rep will be able to re-tag a question in one shot and be able to approve/decline 500- rep retag proposals.
- A set maximum of 30 review tasks / day / user.